# Determining whether the given statements is true or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

$Problem$

Statement 1) $(A\subset C 
    ~\land~ B\subset D
) ~\to~ (A\times B)\subset (C\times D)$

Statement 2) $(A\times B)\subset (C\times D)~\to~(A\subset C 
    ~\land~  B\subset D
)$

Statement 3) Statement 2 if sets A and B are not empty

It is easy to see that statement 1 is true . I am confused about statement 2 and statement 3. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please formate your logical expression - the 'and' leaves it ambiguously interpretable.

Comment: @blueboy First: What is the converse?  Can you state it?  (or at least, make an attempt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To avoid trivialities, let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets (the empty set is a subset of any set) such that $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D$. Suppose $(x,y) \in A \times B$. So $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, by [definition of Cartesian product](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cartesian_Product). Since $A \subset C \land B \subset D$, we have that $x \in C$ and $y \in D $. This means that $(x,y) \in C \times D$, and so $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D).$
2. Consider $A=\{0,1\}$, $B= \emptyset$, $C=\{0\}$, and $D=\{1\}$. Since $A \times \emptyset = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subset \{(0,1)\}=C \times D$, we have that $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D)$ **but** clearly $\neg(A \subset C)$ ($1 \in A$ but $1 \notin C$) .
3. This is true and I will leave it to you (1 and 2 seem like a good hint).

**Note**: The issue with 2 is that we may possibly have $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$. If either of these cases is true, then $A \times B = \emptyset$ and so $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D)$ for any sets $C$ and $D$. In other words, the issue with **not** stating the assumption "$A$ and $B$ are non-empty" is that we might suppose $(x,y) \in A \times B$ when no such pair of elements even exists.